# Regular Expression Data Annotation for URL not working

Tags: .net, wpf, regex, data-annotations

The Regular Expression Data Annotation I am trying to use for the WPF MVVM app I am working on  is hit and miss and does not seem to work with a lot of regexs.

This one works (not for url but something simple):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
```

This, and every other url validation regex I have tried, does not:

```
[RegularExpression(@"/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/")]
```

Does anyone have an example of a working URL regex for use with Data Annotations and WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the starting and ending slashes, .net doesn't need regex delimiters. Also the anchors are not needed here, the pattern is automatically matched against the whole input.

```
[RegularExpression(@"(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?")]
```

should work better. Also removed some unneeded escaping. I haven't checked the pattern itself for correctness!

Comment: Thanks. The pattern does not work and removing leading and following slashes and anchors has not helped other examples. I will reword the question to simply see if anyone has a working regex for use with Data Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out more about validating URLs from this [How to validate URLs with regular expressions](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/280-how-to-validate-urls-with-regular-expressions/) article.

Here is one of their suggestions which works on a wide variety of URLs:

**^((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp).)[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$**

As @stema said, please show any URLs that you are trying to validate if you have any problems with this.

Comment: Thanks @Sheridan. The problem has not been finding URL regexs, there are lots of very good resources. The problem is that the Regular Expression Data Annotation does not seem to work properly, even for very simple regexs like numbers only. I have had to move on so will see if anyone can provide an example of the full validation attribute, including regex, then attempt further testing later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is My Suggestion for Url Data Annotation Regular Expression. It works fine for me.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?$")]
```